# pass data from one viewcontroller to another contains nil in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to swift programming and also referred many posts here, but didn't find solution to my problem. I apologise if am being stupid here

I am trying to pass data from one viewcontroller to another programatically. But even if I pass the value from class B to class A, it says nil

**class A**

```
class testA : UIViewController {
  let objectb = testB()
  var viewlet = [String]!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if viewlet == nil {
      objectb.ready()
    }
    else {
      let sel : Selector = NSSelectorFromString(viewlet[0])
      self.perform(sel)
    }
  }
}
```

**class B**

```
class testB : UIViewController {
  func ready() {
    let vc = testA() 
    vc.viewlet = ["loadpage"]       
    show(vc, sender: self)
  }
}
```

but in class testA, `viewlet` will be nil even after I am passing the value. Am I doing it wrong? or is there any other method ? Thank You for any help

Comment: You can see this link(Though it is in Swift 2 but you can understand :p) - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39285588/how-to-pass-data-from-child-to-parent-view-controller-in-swift/39288232#39288232

Comment: How is this program compiling? You should change var viewlet = [String]! to var viewlet:[String]!

Answer (score 0):

Everytime you do TestA() or TestB(), you're creating a new copy of it. 
This should be what you're trying to do.

```
   class testA : UIViewController {
          let objectb = testB()
          var viewlet = [String]()

          override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
               if viewlet == nil {
               objectb.vc = self
               objectb.ready()
              } else {
                let sel : Selector = NSSelectorFromString(viewlet[0])
                self.perform(sel)
              }
          }
       }

  class testB : UIViewController {
     let vc : testA?
        func ready() {
            vc.viewlet = ["loadpage"]       
            show(vc, sender: self)
          }
        }
```